# Private Route with Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I am trying to create a private route which checks user authentication. But the Private route renders before data from redux Is updated. The component has like isauthenticated variable which eventually updates to true but the component renders  first before it gets updated. As the redux has its value as false at 1st render.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest}) =>{
    return(
        <Route {...rest} render={
            (props) => {
                if(isAuthenticated) { 
                    return <Component {...props}/>
                }else{
                    return <Redirect to="/login"/>
                }

            }
        }/>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return{
        isAuthenticated: state.token !== null
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(PrivateRoute)
```

Comment: Can you describe when and how isAuthenticated updating?

Comment: It sounds like your application architecture is not correct, this route should be 'active' after the login has succeeded - its hard to say where the problem arises  do you have a github link

Comment: @RamanNikitsenka, the isAuthenticated is updated in App.js (componentdidmount) which dispatch an action that gets the token from the localstorage if logged in. https://github.com/DarshanK777/RevaFrontend/blob/master/src/App.js

Comment: @dorriz, https://github.com/DarshanK777/RevaFrontend/blob/master/src/App.js -- link to app.js of project where the isAuthenticated is updated. https://github.com/DarshanK777/RevaFrontend/blob/master/src/store/actions/auth.js -- link to the function which updates the isAuthenticated

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your router inside an `auth-is-loaded` component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { isLoaded } from "react-redux-firebase";

export default function AuthIsLoaded({ children }) {
  const auth = useSelector(state => state.firebase.auth);

  if (isLoaded(auth)) return children;
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
}
```

So App.js will be like this:

```
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <AuthIsLoaded>
            <NavBar />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/about" component={About} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
                <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
                <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} />
              </Switch>
            </AuthIsLoaded>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  );
```

So after auth loaded your switch will be rendered PrivateRoutes wont get isAuthenticated before redux load it.

Sorry about some extra code, I copied from my app, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can add this option:

```js
{ pure: false }
```

to connect and you should be good to go.

```js
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, {
  pure: false,
})(PrivateRoute);
```